# Process.start in vb can't load modules

Tags: vb.net, powershell, azure

I need to start a script ps1 (azure) from vb, i tried to :

```
Process.Start("powershell.exe", "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -noexit 'C:\test.ps1' ")
```

but my powershell just have 1 module loaded, it can't load my azure module and i can't import-module azure

if you have any ideas that will be great ! thx

Comment: Are you running `As Admin`

Comment: nop but when i run without admin manually it work's. I don't know how to run as admin with Process.Start in vb